# Handlebars helper - returning HTML not text

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper

I wrote a simple helper for my template. Here's the code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('splitQuote', function (string) {
    if (string.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
        return string.replace('|', '<span>') + '</span>';
    }
    return string;
});
```

So I pass a string, and split the string by '|' character. I also want to put second part into span tags.

Problem is, the result that is being returned is pure text, so I get span tags like a text, not HTML.

Does anyone know what's the catch?

Tnx

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to mark the string as html in your helper if you want to Handlebars not to escape it. Use [`Handlebars.safeString`](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#helpers) to do this. The below should suit your needs

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('splitQuote', function(string) {
    if (string.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(string.replace('|', '<span>') + '</span>');
    }
    return string;
});
```

As mentioned in comments you should probably escape the passed string using `Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(string)` to encode the string before you do your custom formatting. I'd recommend writing like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('splitQuote', function(string) {
    string = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(string);
    if (string.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
        string = string.replace('|', '<span>') + '</span>';
    }
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(string); // mark as already escaped
});
```

Comment: You should manually HTML encode `string` before adding the `<span>`s if you're going to use SafeString.

Answer (score 51):

You don´t need to use `SafeString`. Instead, use the "triple moustaches" from handlebar:

From [Handlebars web site](http://handlebarsjs.com/), HTML Escaping section:

*Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.*

So, a simple triple quote in your html will avoid escaping:

```
{{{splitQuote}}}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer / preferred way to do this